# Is the second locative used with при?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, предлоги

Grammars and various other linguistic publications generally state that the second locative is used only with в and на (e.g. в лесу, в аэропорту).  However, it seems to me that I have come across examples with при as well.

Comment: Could you please share these examples?

Answer (score 4):

1. In the expressions *при полку, при боку* (of a cold weapon):

   > - Если при полку оркестра нет, сигналисты-барабанщики, предварительно построенные на месте оркестра, бьют «Под Знамя».
   >   *[Строевой устав Вооружённых Сил Российской Федерации (1993)]*
   > - — Прежде имели мы право хоть саблю при боку носить, а теперь отымают они от нас и это последнее право!
   >   *[М. П. Старицкий. Первые коршуны (1893)]*
2. In poetry, for rhythmic purposes or archaic stylizations: *при лужку; при вечеру-вечерочку; при пиру, при беседушке* (all from song lyrics).

Both *при полку* and *при боку* are idiomatic, but the nouns do accept modifiers: *при нашем полку, при левом боку*.

*При полку* is (idiomatically) synonymous to *в полку*, but the preposition is technically used in its narrow sense of "as a subordinate or dependent, but not a proper part of".

Very rarely in this sense does it govern the locative of other nouns:

> - Цех покраски расположен в Краснодаре, при цеху действует склад металлопроката, производство металлоконструкций.
> - В здании бывшей мини-гостиницы при аэропорту они развернули пост наблюдения: на крышу выкинули несколько антенн.

Comment: Thank you.  But now there is a follow-up necessary.  In Russian (and not only, Latin, Polish, etc. also do this) one often finds forms like this preserved in idioms, which moreover may really be so frozen they are really words.  F.ex. some people have argued that the genitive in из дому is a separate case, but this is not so clear.   It is likely that izdomu is actually an adverb.  One way to make sure is to ask whether one can say при аэропорту with some new noun.  Another is to ask whether we can say при нашем полку.   In the case of при боку I suspect that it is now a single word.

Comment: As mentioned by @CocoPop, using "A при B" in "при цеху действует склад" and "мини-гостиницы при аэропорту" points to the location (at the hotel). However, it also tells that the A is an addition and wasn't initially an intrinsic part of B. As for idiomatic, the same meaning was carried over to the idiomatic form from the initial usage. E.q. in "служить при полку" was carried over from the "служить при ком-то", "служить при полку (дворе) кого-то". However, in modern russian, those are stable expressions where "при" is synonymous with "в".

Comment: @AttilathePun "из дому" is (accepted and widely used) vulgarization/archaization. The correct form is "из дома" which has the correct ending "а" for Genetive 2nd declension. As for "single word", it is called "устойчивое выражение", a stable expression. There are, indeed, many of those in the russian language; some are archaic forms that people still like using, and some come from "vulgar" russian, dialects, and even foreign languages (also commonly vulgarised to fit the russian phonetics). I do believe though, that this is not unique to the russian or other slavic languages.

Comment: Please don't write nonsense.  Thank you.